# Doctrine2 - delete salt, password columns in findById request

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm

I have a Symfony API that send JSON from doctrine request. I need to send users details but I do not want to send the salt and password column of FosUsers.

I have a `member` class extending the base user class. When I use doctrine to request a member by id, the attributes salt and password from the user class are also fetched.

How can I handle this problem? Is "partial" request the only way to solve this?

```
    $member =  $this->getDoctrine()->getManager()
        ->getRepository('ApiUserBundle:member')
        ->findOneById($request->get('id'));

    $view = View::create($member);
    $view->setFormat('json');

    return $view;
```

Comment: How are you serializing these objects to JSON? The solution would be in implementing some serialization rules that skip these fields when serializing.

Comment: I use the view layer of FOSRestBundle to serialize the data into JSON. Where can I define serialization rules ?

Comment: What are you passing to the view layer for data? Can you update your question with snippets of this code?

Comment: You can use JMS serializer with FOSRestBundle and then have the opportunity to have exclude/expose possibility by annotations/yaml/xml http://jmsyst.com/libs/serializer/master/reference/annotations. You can make excludePolicy to none and then exclude password and salt only.